# htaccess rewrite rule preventing access newly added php files

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have a website with htaccess file. the htaccess has lot of codes. when I create a new php file it redirects to another page. so I checked my htaccess file and remove a one line of code

```
RewriteRule ^.*\.{1}(htm|html|php)\/?   index.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

after that the file can can able to access diretly. can anyone know the meaning of above htacess and how can it effect for newly added php files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^.*\.{1}(htm|html|php)\/?   index.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

is silently forwarding every request URI with extension `.php` OR `.htm` OR `.html` to `index.php`

So even if you add a new `.php` above regex `^.*\.{1}(htm|html|php)\/?` will match and request for the newly created file will still be forwarded to `index.php`

**PS:** This rule doesn't make lot sense though a similar looking rule is used in many front controllers like Wordpress, CodeIgnitor, Cake etc frameworks.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)